# combining DropoutWrapper and ResidualWrapper with variational_recurrent=True

Tags: tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, dropout, deep-residual-networks

I'm trying to create a MultiRNNCell of LSTM cells wrapped with both DropoutWrapper and ResidualWrapper. For using variational_recurrent=True, we must provide input_size parameter to DropoutWrapper. I'm not able figure out what input_size should be passed to each LSTM layer, since ResidualWrapper also adds skip connections to augment the input at each layer.

I'm using the following utility function to create one LSTM layer:

```
def create_cell(units, residual_connections, keep_prob, input_size):
    lstm_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(units,
                                        activation=tf.nn.tanh,
                                        initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(),
                                        cell_clip=5.)
    lstm_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper(lstm_cell,
                                              dtype=tf.float32,
                                              input_keep_prob=keep_prob,
                                              output_keep_prob=keep_prob,
                                              state_keep_prob=keep_prob,
                                              variational_recurrent=True,
                                              input_size=input_size)

    if residual_connections:
        lstm_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.ResidualWrapper(lstm_cell)
    return lstm_cell
```

And the following code to create the complete cell:

```
net = tf.layers.dense(inputs,
                      128,
                      activation=tf.nn.relu, 
                      kernel_initializer=tf.variance_scaling_initializer())
net = tf.layers.batch_normalization(net, training=training)    
cells = [create_cell(64, False, keep_prob, ??)]
for _ in range(5):
    cells.append(create_cell(64, True, keep_prob, ??))
multirnn_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell(cells)
net, rnn_s1 = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell=multirnn_cell, inputs=net, initial_state=rnn_s0, dtype=tf.float32)
```

What values should be passed to input_size for first and subsequent LSTM layers?